# OFX Connectivity options

Tags: banking, ofx

We currently use a product from NSoftware that allows us to connect to banks directly using the OFX protocol to download transactions and balances.

OFX is functional on a lot of banks, but I was hoping to get insight from others who have used other methods of banking connectivity.  Screen scraping and OFX are the only two we know of.

Does anyone out there have any advice on API's or other options we may have missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for asking about bank support for OFX and your wesabe link below.  I am getting tired of the Quicken / qfx monopoly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yodlee, or wasabe open source as they just went belly up and published their code.

Comment: I'm currently using Yodlee.  It's expensive and has a horrible API.  But I'll look into the Wesabe thing.  I remember my boss asked me to look into that once, so I'll revisit it.  Thanks for the comprehensive and well worded answer!

Comment: Hi guys, Would one of you post a link to the open source wasabe, pleaes? (googled for it but cannot fint id). Thanks :)

Comment: There is also intuit but with a minimum of $1000 per month or $0.30 per user which ever is higher the cost for a small developer is probably out of reach